# "[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/x86_84-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so' : file not found"

Tags: mysql, node.js, odbc

Not used to linux at all so forgive me. It seems as though I have been through every post online for this issue and I've finally come to post my own.

I need to connect to a MySQL Database via an ODBC connector. I know javascript so I am using [nodes odbc module](https://github.com/markdirish/node-odbc/). I have successfully built unixodbc and all of that.

My odbc.ini is located in /etc/ and looks like this (I've obfuscated some parts):

```
[eFaradayDSN]
Description = ****
Driver = MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver
Server = **.**.*.45
User = ***
Password = *****
Port = 3306
Database = ****
```

My odbcinst.ini is location in /etc/ also and looks like:

```
[MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver]
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_84-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so
UsageCount=1

[MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver]
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_84-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8a.so
UsageCount=1

[eFaradayDSN]
Description = ***
Driver = MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver
Server = **.**.*.45
User = ****
Password = *****
Port = 3306
Database = *****
```

Doing an odbcinst -j returns:

```
odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.6
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

There are no missing dependencies showing via ldd:

```
ldd -v /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so
```

I have updated the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, PATH and ODBCINI env variables:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PWD=/root
LOGNAME=root
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
MOTD_SHOWN=pam
HOME=/root
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
TERM=xterm-256color
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
USER=root
SHLVL=1
XDG_SESSION_ID=454
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0
SSH_CLIENT=86.206.239.102 51232 22
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/x886+64-linux-gnu/odbc
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/0/bus
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/3
OLDPWD=/etc/ODBCDataSources
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

**UPDATE**

I reinstalled the .deb odbc connector driver (I think that is what is is) and now when running my node program I have a new error:

```
[Error: [odbc] Error connecting to the database] {


odbcErrors: [
    {
      state: 'HY000',
      code: 1045,
      message: "[MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver]Access denied for user '<the username in my DSN>'@'127.0.0.1 <I have also tried the actual ip here>' (using password: YES)"
    }
  ]
}
```

So the message source has changed from unixODBC to MySQL - I assume that means I am reaching the database server ok now...?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this to works. The steps were quite simple in the end.

1. As per my update I reinstalled the drivers
2. Changed the username from what I thought it should be to 'root'

This worked.

Comment: I hope this helps someone